# Would my infant daughter born in UK need a TB screening test to return to UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, dependent-visa, children

My daughter was born in UK in Fenruary 2018. She left UK on 25 April 2018 with her mother to go back home to Pakistan. I am now applying for her visa to join me in March 2019. Would she need to get her TB test done and attached with her application?

The TB test gov link states the following:

> You will not need a TB test if any of the following apply:
>
> - you’re a diplomat accredited to the UK
> - you’re a returning UK resident and have not been away for more than 2 years
> - you lived for at least 6    months in a country where TB screening is not required by the UK, and    you’ve been away from that country
>   for no more than 6 months

Does she fall under the second point as she was born in UK and has not been away fro more than 2 year?

Comment: BCG is usually administered at birth in Pakistan, so it's possible that it would have been routinely administered when she moved out there. I see that it's also now offered at birth by the NHS to babies whose parents come from countries which are considered high-risk. So it's probably worth checking whether you or the mother have a certificate of vaccination.

Comment: [Lourdes Da Fonseca Raju](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/20253/lourdes-da-fonseca-raju) - "I am in exactly the same situation as yourself and the country in Africa where my child is in have said they have never been in such a situation and cannot do a TB test for a child 3 years old without doing the test for the parent who will travel with the child, basically they usually add this to the parents test as parents usually apply the same time with their kids. Tell me if the documentation from health check was sufficient for your case / what you provided for your childs application?"

Comment: @LourdesDaFonsecaRaju,  [StuckInPhD](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/13619/stuckinphd) - "Hi, I did end up getting an appointment for her and the doctor asked a few questions from the mother and have us the TB certificate for my daughter. It was a required document."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your little one was born in the UK, she may not be considered a returning resident, was about 2 months old when she left and has been in Pakistan for the last 8 months. Pakistan is among those [countries whose visa applicants require TB testing](https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa/countries-where-you-need-a-tb-test-to-enter-the-uk).

While you have the correct UK link, [Tuberculosis tests for visa applicants](https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa), the section following what you cite says this about children (added emphasis mine).

> **Children**
>
> All children must see a clinician who’ll decide if they need a chest x-ray. Children under 11 will not normally have a chest x-ray.
>
> You must take your child to an approved clinic and complete a health questionnaire. **If the clinician decides your child does not have TB they’ll give you a certificate. Include this certificate with your child’s UK visa application.**

Her clinic visit will determine whether a TB test is required. Either way, you will need to include the documentation from the health check with your visa application.